# Laravel Rate Limiting with a message and remaining time after validation

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have two problem:
Problem one is when i'm limiting a post request by laravel in-built rate limitter it's also counting when a validation is failed and the request is no complete and i want to limit it when the request is successfully done.

**this is my code for rate limit:**

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('throttle:3,10')->only('registerVerification');
    }
```

and the Problem two is i want to show a message when the user reaches the limit for that request and show the remaining time to retry like Jetstream Rate Limiting but currently its redirecting to error page(429).

is there any way to customize these things?

Comment: Create a file called `429.blade.php` in this `/resources/views/errors/` folder.

Comment: @Droid I know and i have error views and already customized them, i dont want to redirect to that page and instead show a message at same page with time remaining to retry